# How to get task count in GCP cloud task

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Is there any standard way to get cloud task count for a queue?

I know we can loop through `nextPageToken` and achieve this.

Can this be achieved with single request?

Comment: I was able to figure this out, cloudtask v2beta3 has a feature to request for stats of queue

https://gist.github.com/sameershaik1996/f0e4d724dd52708cb04161450b3e8bc8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the documentation, [QueueStats](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-tasks/latest/com/google/cloud/tasks/v2beta2/QueueStats.html#getTasksCount--) seems to be the standard way to get task count.

As mentioned in @Sameer comment, [cloudtask v2beta3](https://gist.github.com/sameershaik1996/f0e4d724dd52708cb04161450b3e8bc8) has a feature to request for stats of a queue:

```
public long geQueueDepth(String queuePath) {
        long depth=-1;

       try {
           FieldMask.Builder fieldBuilder = FieldMask.newBuilder();
           fieldBuilder.addPaths("stats");
           com.google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.GetQueueRequest queueRequest =
                   com.google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.GetQueueRequest.newBuilder().setName(queuePath).setReadMask(fieldBuilder).build();;
           com.google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.Queue queue = cloudTasksClientV3.getQueue(queueRequest);
           depth=queue.getStats().getTasksCount();
          
       }catch (Exception e){
           LOGGER.error("Error while getting queue depth =>{}",e.getMessage());
       }
        return depth;
    }
```

Comment: Would be helpful to clarify if `setReadMask` removes default ReadMasks (looks like it from the code) and if `mergeReadMask` would be a better option if one whishes to remain the default ReadMasks.

Comment: Tested it and it seems to me that it is not possible to preserve the other default masks  (guess this is because the default set is determined on the server and not on the client).

In theory a complete set of masks ("name,rateLimits,retryConfig,state,taskTtl,tombstoneTtl,type,stats") should be passed, however I didn't get this to work in java, stuck with an "Invalid read mask paths" error for mask which I think should work. If anybody has a suggestion I'm grateful for suggestions.